# How to send a JSON data object to the server using Javascript XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I send  an XMLHttp Request to a PHP server. I cannot get hte `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` object filled with the data I send using Javascript:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest;

r.open("POST", "http://url.com", true);

r.send({ myname : 'someName'});
```

I cannot access `myname` property in the `$_POST` array, though I see in `php://input`. How should I have it in `$_POST` as well? I have tried to send the data like this:

```
r.send(JSON.stringify({ myname : 'someName'}));
```

But it does neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will not populate `$_POST` for an `application/json` request.

(You aren't actually sending a proper JSON request because you forgot to set the `Content-Type` header on your XHR object, but the data will be invalid in any other format so the end result is the same.)

It will only do so for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` data.

If you want to populate `$_POST` then don't use JSON as your data format. (You could use JSON embedded in the URL Encoded format, but that would just give you a string representation of a JSON text in `$_POST['json']` and wouldn't give you direct access to the data encoded in the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://url.com", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ myname : "someName"}));
```

Comment: That will send a valid JSON request. It won't populate `$_POST` though, which is what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
r.open('POST','http://url.com',true);
r.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
r.setRequestHeader("Content-length", string.length);
r.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");   
r.send({ myname : 'someName'});
```

Comment: That will send a valid JSON request. It won't populate `$_POST` though, which is what the question is asking about.